# How make an observable buffer data till an event happen and stop buffering?

Tags: rxjs

I have outward stream of drawing from an user and I need wait till  data of the user profile come.

So in general I want buffer data till an event happens and then play this data and skip buffering.

I can do it with external array like the follow code show ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-eb58ul?devtoolsheight=60)):

```js
    import { of, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
    import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

    const numbers = interval(1000);
    const source = numbers.pipe(
      take(4)
    );
    let allowPerform = false;
    setTimeout(_=>{allowPerform = true},2001);
    const fifo=[];
    source.subscribe(x => {
      fifo.push(x);
      if (!allowPerform) {
         console.log('skip perform for:', x);
         return; 
      }

      let item ;  
      while ( fifo.length) {
        item = fifo.shift(); 
        console.log('perform for:', item);
      } 
    });
```

it's output:

```
skip perform for: 0
skip perform for: 1
perform for: 0
perform for: 1
perform for: 2
perform for: 3
```

However how to do it in RXjs's way?

Comment: RxJs has the [`buffer` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffer) which does just that. You might have to add a `first()` after `buffer()` to make sure the buffering is done once.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the `external` part. You can either do that logic in `subscribe`'s first callback, or, use `tap(arr => externalArr = arr)`, after `buffer()` and `first()`

Comment: it is only first part of answer. I need skip buffering after it does not need.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kwcoth?file=index.ts
notice this example show only:
result 0
result 1
instead show till result 9 


I do not get how skip buffering.

Comment: Can you show how use first in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Here could be a way to do this:

```js
// Buffer until the `notifier` emits
// Then do not buffer anymore, just send the values

const src$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(10), publish(), refCount());
const notifier$ = timer(2001);

concat(
  src$.pipe(buffer(notifier$), mergeAll()),
  src$
).subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.warn('complete'));
```

Using `publish(), refCount()` will multicast the emitted values to all the consumers. This is achieved by placing a `Subject` between the source and the data consumers, meaning that the source won't be subscribed multiple times.

`src$.pipe(buffer(notifier$), mergeAll()),` will buffer until `notifier$` emits. But, because `notifier$` also completes, the entire observable passed will complete, allowing for the next observable(`src$`) to be subscribed.
`mergeAll()` is used because `buffer` will emit an array of the collected values and with `mergeAll()` we can get the values separately.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/buffer-once-then-nah?file=index.ts)